# Getting text from a entry window in Python graphics

Tags: string, python-3.x, text, zelle-graphics

```
from graphics import *      

win = GraphWin("Hangman", 600, 600)
win.setBackground("yellow")
textEntry = Entry(Point(233,200),10)
textEntry.draw(win)
text = textEntry.getText()
testText = Text(Point(150,15), text)
testText.draw(win)

exitText = Text(Point(200,50), 'Click anywhere to quit')
exitText.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

I'm trying to obtain text from the user in Python graphics and be able to use that input, such as manipulate it, search for it in a list, etc. To test that, I created a entry window in graphics and tried to obtain the text from that entry window and simply display it in the window, just to check if it sucessfully obtained the text.

Unfortunately, it isn't working, it just shows the 'Click anywhere to quit' and then the empty window and despite writing text in it it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comes from the [documentation](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html#entry-objects).

> The way the underlying events are hidden in graphics.py, there is no signal when the user is done entering text in an Entry box. To signal the program, a mouse press is used above. In this case the location of the mouse press is not relevant, but once the mouse press is processed, execution can go on and read the Entry text.

You're getting the text right after you draw the Entry, so it will be empty. You need to wait for a signal, then read the Entry. This excerpt from the documentation says to wait for a mouse click then read the Entry.
So try to add the

```
    win.getMouse()
```

to your code as follows

```
from graphics import *      

win = GraphWin("Hangman", 600, 600)
win.setBackground("yellow")
textEntry = Entry(Point(233,200),50)
textEntry.draw(win)

# click the mouse to signal done entering text
win.getMouse()

text = textEntry.getText()
testText = Text(Point(150,15), text)
testText.draw(win)

exitText = Text(Point(200,50), 'Click anywhere to quit')
exitText.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Here's what the output looks like. Note: I made the Entry 50 wide.
[image: output of testing the modified code]